# How do nice carriage return output of variable-length strings without overlapping the strings?

Tags: python, carriage-return

How can I print simple info about script progress with carriage return when the strings I want to vary in length, while preventing that the strings overlap? See this simple example

```
import sys
import time
fewds = ["raspberry", "orange", "pineapple", "fig", "honeysuckle"]

for f in fewds:
    sys.stdout.write(f+"\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can keep track of the length of the last line you printed, and use [str.ljust](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.ljust) to add the necessary spaces to the next one in order to completely cover the previous line.

> str.ljust(width[, fillchar])
>
> Return the string left justified in a
>   string of length width. Padding is done using the specified fillchar
>   (default is an ASCII space). The original string is returned if width
>   is less than or equal to len(s).

So, your code would be:

```
import sys
import time
fewds = ["raspberry", "orange", "pineapple", "fig", "honeysuckle"]

last_length = 0
for f in fewds:
    sys.stdout.write(f.ljust(last_length) + "\r")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.5)
    last_length = len(f)
```